# Creating URL from String

Tags: ios, swift, url, swift4

I have problem with following code:
String URL works fine in browser, but cant create URL from it.

```
    let stringURL = "http://dev.rationaletech.com:8063/Images/Offers/1/20%25-off-at-gloria-jean’s-coffee-6b62e43e-ba2b-4c9c-9f70-8b24e2a514a0.jpg"
    let url = URL(string:stringURL)
```

url property is nil after.

I have realized that problem is caused by ’ character inside link.

Any suggestions?

Update:

I have done next:

```
    let charactesSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "#<>^`{|}").inverted
    if let stringUrl = stringURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: charactesSet){
        let url = URL(string:stringURL)
    }
```

where charactesSet is  URLHostAllowedCharacterSet      "#%/<>?@\^`{|}" without %. And now i have:
http://dev.rationaletech.com:8063/Images/Offers/1/20%25-off-at-gloria-jean%E2%80%99s-coffee-6b62e43e-ba2b-4c9c-9f70-8b24e2a514a0.jpg
which works. I dont like this solution, will talk to server side. tnx

Comment: Tip: `jean’s-coffee` => `jeans-coffee` make it works (it's not nil, I'm not saying if the URL is valid not 404 or not). You might want to "percent escape" characters (that's some keyword to search).

Comment: Thank you @Larme

Comment: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/how-to-percent-encode-a-url-string/

Comment: Thanks everyone, it looks like server returned half encoded url (encoded % and skiped ’).